# Ruby - How to remove all files in a directory older than X days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a directory of `csv` files called `reports`

I want to delete all files from the `reports` folder that are older than X number of days.

This works great to remove ALL files:

```
FileUtils.rm_rf("reports/.", secure: true)
```

But I want the filter of only remove files older than X number of days.

How?

Comment: Don't forget `find` can do this with the `-delete` option if you want a quick solution.

Comment: Do you determine the age based on the file's stats or is it part of the filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list all file names, then use `File.stat` to check the modification time of each file and remove each one of them.

For instance, you could use the following code:

```rb
# will count X days older than "reference_time"
reference_time = Time.now

# use the following value to delete files older than 30 days
delete_older_than = 30 * (24 * 3600) # value in seconds

all_files = Dir['reports/*']
all_files.each do |relative_file_name|
  # not really necessary, but I like to work with full file paths
  file_path = File.expand_path(relative_file_name)

  # if you want to be strict and delete only files (e.g. not folders),
  # this line skips any non-files.
  next unless File.file?(file_path)

  st = File.stat(file_path)  
  # modification time is at st.mtime

  if st.mtime < (reference_time - delete_older_than)
    File.unlink(file_path)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can also be structured as a series of `select` or `reject` operations, and then a final `File.unlink` on the resulting array. I find it's usually a good idea to test code like this before it inadvertently, say, deletes everything in your home directory or worse.